# Looking for a small mixer with jacks on the BACK

Tags: home-studio

Most small mixers (Yamaha MG10X, Mackie Mix8) have the connectors on top.

I am trying to fit my home studio into a small desk, and it would be nice not to have to leave that much vertical space over the top of the back of mixer.  My cabling doesn't change frequently, so quick access is not an issue.

Is anyone aware of a small (5 to 10 channel) mixer with connections on the BACK?  Allen and Heath MixWizard lets you rotate the connector panel, but is way bigger than I need or have space for.  There are level-only mixers, but I want pan, eq, and at least a few mic channels.

Worst-case, I could use right-angle plugs, but I hate to have to do custom cables for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick browse through a sound gear shop shows that all of their small analog mixers have their inputs on top. There are older mixers with inputs on the back (I've used the Tascam M-06, and a Behringer Eurorack 2642), so that's an option if you're willing to accept secondhand gear.

Alternatives:

- a 19" rackmount mixer ([random example](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/MultiMix12R--alesis-multimix-12r-rackmount-mixer))
- a remote-controlled digital mixer ([like these](https://www.sweetwater.com/c265--Digital_Mixers?params=eyJmYWNldCI6eyJQcmljZSBSYW5nZSI6WyI1IiwiNiJdfX0))

Comment: Thanks, Hobbes, for a survey of my options.

Comment: Something like the Tascam has the right form factor, with connectors on the back.  BUT its mic ins are quarter-inch, and line ins are RCA, so I would need to re-cable.

Which suggests that my best solution is to re-cable using right-angle jacks, which would allow me to use just about ANY current small mixer.  Thanks for guiding me to the simplest solution.